# What's the frame to write Kinect skeleton track program with gesture users can define with C#?

Tags: kinect

I'm writing program about Kinect skeleton track program.While the Definition of the gesture is  written in the program. I want the definition of gesture to be defined by the user.One way of doing this is by DFA. I don't konw how to start with C#. Can any one help?

Comment: Two gesture libraries already available for Kinect that may server your purpose or provide inspiration: http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/ and https://github.com/EvilClosetMonkey/Fizbin.Kinect.Gestures

Answer (score 0):

Try using Lists to store the coordinates of the skeleton's joints (kind of a buffer) and then you could maybe run a DFA. you could define your transitions as a range of coordinates for every direction , and the final state would be when the elements in the buffer are approximativily in the same area.

So in C# you will need to create a datatype to save the sequece of the gesture that will get updated when the user adds one.Lists for buffers as I stated below.

When saving the gesture your code will look like :

```
  While(!Joint_stable && (i < buffer.count() ) )
{
 While ((buffer.Joint.ElementAt(i+1).X-buffer.Joint.ElementAt(i)).X>0 && (buffer.Joint.ElementAt(i+1)-buffer.Joint.ElementAt(i).Y )>0 ) //Think about adding tolerence here
 { 
Gesture.add("Upper_Right");
 }
 ...
}
```

Just an advice , the kinect sensor is not that accurate so try to establish a kind of tolerance.

I Hope that my answer will help you or at least give you some inspiration :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice,I will try it.While I do find no good principles  to estimate the accuracy of the gesture state,I'll think about it for a while.